# Create binary tree from tree (n-ary)

Tags: binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I  want to solve the problem given in the image below.

[image]

Comment: This is not a problem -- it's just a picture

Comment: read that question which is in the top.If you cant here the question is  Convert the given tree to binary tree. Do you know binary tree??

Comment: Binary trees and general trees are different data structures, they are, so to say, not topologically equivalent. Therefore, at least you have to state some properties the solution should possess.

Comment: @davidhigh it has to posess binary tree properties

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. T

Comment: @user1639485 in which way?  It was question in exam around 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A New Algorithm to Represent a Given k-ary Tree into Its Equivalent Binary Tree.

[Refer This Paper](http://www.vidyasagar.ac.in/journal/maths/Vol12/JPS12-24.pdf)

In Simple words:
1. Create L to R sibling pointers at each level 
2. Remove all but the leftmost child pointer of each node 
3. Make the sibling pointer the right pointer.